# How can I check if my jar is still running in Windows 10 using another jar?

Tags: monitor

I am an amateur programmer. So if my question below is stupid, then I appologize here already.

I have created a java routine that logs data from sensors to a text file. The jar starts with autostart and is supposed to run 24/7. To not have it on my task bar in windows 10, I have sent it to the tray. So far so good.
However, about once or twice a week the app crashes and the time line of my log readings is interrupted. To debug, I created a log file to which the jar is supposed to send all errors. But no relevant entry there that would explain the crash either. To help myself I created a looped batch job like this:

> :start 
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\java" -jar D:\...\MyApp.jar 
> goto start

That batch works fine. But now I have that batch job on my task bar all the time.
I figured if it might be possible to write another jar (that I can put away into my system tray like my primary app) that acts as a guardian process, checks every few minutes if MyApp is still active and restarts it if needed.

To solve such a problem, I normally surf the net and try to find some code snippet that does something like what I want and adapt that for me. However, I could not find any java code yet with which I can detect if the MyApp process is still active in Windows 10.
Getting the task list from the Win taskmanager will not do since I have several small jars running in the background and when I open the taskmanager I only see generic "runtime broker" entries and no jar names.

Maybe I'm looking for the wrong key words. Can someone help me or push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching around I found the following solution:

```
public static void startExtJarProgram(){
    String extJar = "MyApp.jar";
    //ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(extJar);
    try {
       File f = new File("ClewareMonitorLog.txt");
       ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", extJar);
       processBuilder.redirectError(f);
       Process process = processBuilder.start();
       //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(extJar);
       while (true) {
           String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm").format(new Date());
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, timeStamp + "   - MyApp started.");
           try {
                final int exitStatus = process.waitFor();
                process = processBuilder.start();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException: "+ex.getMessage());
            }               
       }
```

This function acts as a guardian process. It starts the MyApp.jar and then waits for its return (which only happens when the main app terminates). It then checks if the app terminated with an error and if not (= someone accidentally closed it or the java session terminated) restarts it.